# Как поместить switch в actionbar?

Tags: actionbar, activity, android, java, switch

Мои попытки провалились. Выдаёт ошибку при таком коде:

```
Switch swi = new Switch(null);
bar.setCustomView(swi);
```

**Как исправить?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Естественно - Вы ему **null** в конструктор подаёте а нужно **Context** , примерно так :

```
Switch swi = new Switch(yourActivity.getApplicationContext());
```